# Regarding eclipse galileo

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-3.5

I'm using eclipse galileo for developing some web application. But I want to get the eclipse installed on the server(assume some other pc or server machine) and I want to access it as a client and work as I was working before. Please suggest me what type of server I should configure and which Operating System supports it.

Answer (score 0):

A little bit weird to put the IDE on the server but you can use whatever OS you want, put the Eclipse there and connect to it using VNC or Remote Desktop.